# Best way to filter and sort a Map by set of keys

Tags: scala

I have a Map instance (immutable):

```
val source = Map(
    ("foo", "spam"),
    ("bar", "hoge"),
    ("baz", "eggs"),
    ("qux", "corge"),
    ("quux", "grault")
  )
```

and I have number of keys (Set or List) in some order which may or may not exist in source map:

```
baz
foo
quuuuux // does not exist in a source map
```

But what is the best and cleanest way to iterate over the source map with concise scala style, filter it by my keys and place filtered items into resulting map in the same order as keys are?

```
Map(baz -> eggs, foo -> spam)
```

P.S. To clarify - order of keys in resulting map must be the same as in filtration keys list

Comment: You got two answers b/c "same order as keys" could mean either preserve iteration order of source (or even the key Set) or the keys should be ordered. Your example suggests the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val keys = List("foo", "bar")
val map = Map("foo" -> "spam", "bar" -> "hoge", "baz" -> "eggs")

keys.foldLeft(ListMap.empty[String, String]){ (acc, k) => 
  map.get(k) match {
    case Some(v) => acc + (k -> v)
    case None => acc
  }
}
```

This will iterate over the keys, building a map containing only the matching keys.

Please note that you need a `ListMap` to preserve the ordering of keys, although the implementation of `ListMap` will return the elements in the opposite order they were inserted (since keys are prepended as head of the list)

`LinkedHashMap` would ensure exact insertion order, but it's a mutable data structure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but shouldn't I use for example ListMap instead of SortedMap if I really want to preserve order of keys even if it's not alphabetical?

Comment: ListMap makes no guarantees about the ordering of keys. The current implementation happens to preserve order (e.g. on map) but it's not in the spec.

Comment: I've elaborated a little

Comment: It's still true that in the next release, ListMap could be changed to do it in any order. It's simply not part of the "contract" for ListMap to preserve order.

Answer (score 4):

If you have:

```
val source = Map(
  "foo" -> "spam",
  "bar" -> "hoge",
  "baz" -> "eggs",
  "qux" -> "corge",
  "quux" -> "grault"
 )
```

and

```
val keys = List( "baz", "foo", "quuuux" )
```

Then, you can:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

SortedMap(source.toSeq:_*).filter{ case (k,v) => keys.contains(k) }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need an ordered `Map`, you could use something like a `TreeMap` with a custom key ordering. So given

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val source = Map(
  ("foo", "spam"),
  ("bar", "hoge"),
  ("baz", "eggs"),
  ("qux", "corge"),
  ("quux", "grault")
)
val order: IndexedSeq[String] = IndexedSeq("baz", "foo", "quuuuux")
implicit val keyOrdering: Ordering[String] = Ordering.by(order.indexOf)
```

You have choice, either iterate over the ordered keys:

```
val result1: TreeMap[String, String] = order.collect {
  case key if source.contains(key) => key -> source(key)
}(collection.breakOut)

// or a bit shorter
val result2: TreeMap[String, String] = order.flatMap { key => source.get(key).map(key -> _) }(collection.breakOut)
```

or filter from the source map:

```
val result3: TreeMap[String, String] = TreeMap.empty ++ source.filterKeys(order.contains)
```

I am not sure which one would be the most efficient, but I suspect the `flatMap` one might be fastest, at least for your simple example. Though, imho, the last example is better readable than the others.

Comment: I do believe last code example must look like this: val result3 = TreeMap.empty[String, String] ++ source.filterKeys(order.contains)